# Hide URL in ASP.NET application

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting

I am developing an ASP.NET application. But i would like to hide the URL so user don't know on which page he or she standing. Is their any solution?

Comment: What do you mean by hiding the `URL`? From browser address bar? If it is what you are looking for, then No is the answer.. But you can try changing into different `route` as explained in different way **[here](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/How-to-hide-remove-ASPX-extension-in-URL-in-ASPNet.aspx)**

Comment: Yes, hiding the URL isn't any more possible than it is possible to publish a book in such a way that readers can't look at the cover.

Comment: Yes like in other site URL will be rewrite when you browse any page.

Comment: You can use `Encryption` in `Querystring`

Answer (score 1):

Use     `Server.Transfer` . It doesn't change the URL.

`Server.Transfer` happens without the browser knowing anything, the browser request a page, but the server returns the content of another.

**Server.Transfer() should be used when:**

- we don't need to show the real URL   where we redirected the request
  in the users Web Browser
- we want to transfer current page request to another .aspx page on the
  same server
- we want to preserve server resources and avoid the    unnecessary
  roundtrips to the server
- we want to preserve Query String and Form Variables (optionally)

Comment: You can't hide the main URL like www.YourWebsite.com. Also replace all Response.Redirect with Server.Transfer

Answer (score 0):

There is no solution unless you can force the user to browse only from a restricted environment in which you can control what software is installed or run. Even if you force the user to use a specific browser, they could use a tool like Fiddler to see what URLs they are going to.